# In SSRS, How to show two columns in drop down of parameter value?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS, How to show two columns in drop down of parameter value ? For Example, how to show Product id and Name in drop down of parameter ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a **Calculated Field** which concatenates the `ProductID` and `ProductName` in the **Dataset** you're using to populate your **Parameter**.

e.g. with the **Dataset**:

[image]

I created a new **Calculated Field** called `ProductIDName` with the expression:

```
=CStr(Fields!ProductID.Value) & ": " & Fields!ProductName.Value
```

Now use this new field to populate your **Parameter**:

[image]

End result:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting it and setting it as the accepted answer.